# How do I make method param mutable in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm implementing a `SpinnerAdapter` in Android project. So I have to override `getView(i: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup)` method. So `convertView` is here in order to reuse existing view and reduce memory usage and GC occurrences. So if it is `null` I have to create view and use already created otherwise.

So in fact I have to write something like this (officially recomended by google):

```
if (view == null) {
    view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_spinner, parent)
    view.tag(Holder(view))
} else {
    (view.tag as Holder).title.text = getItem(i)
}
```

But Kotlin does not allow to write to param.
What I found on the internet is an official [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/02/kotlin-m5-1/) that says that it is not possible since Feb, 2013.

So I'm wondering if there is any workaround ?

Comment: Use a separate variable. There is no need to assign a value to the parameter.

Comment: than `convertView` param will always be null so each time new view will be created. It make views recycling mechanism totally useless

Comment: @oleg.semen no, if you return non-null `View` from `getView` method that `View` will be later used as a `convertView` - use a separate variable as Henry said

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how parameters in Java work. They are basically local variables which are initialised with the actual parameter. Changing them inside the method has no effect to the caller.

Comment: @pskink thanks, got it

Comment: In other words in JVM parameters are always passed *by value*, never *by reference*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, you are mistakenly assuming that modifying `view` in Java does anything outside of the current function scope.  It does not.  You setting that parameter to a new value affects nothing outside of the local function scope.

```
View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
   // modify view here does nothing to the original caller reference to view
   // but returning a view does do something
}
```

Next, in Kotlin all parameters are `final` (JVM modifier, also same as `final` modifier in Java).  The Kotlin `if` statement version of this code would be:

```
fun getView(i: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
   return if (view == null) {
       val tempView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_spinner, parent)
       tempView.tag(Holder(tempView))
       tempView
   } else { 
       (view.tag as Holder).title.text = getItem(i)
       view
   }
}
```

or avoiding the new local variable:

```
fun getView(i: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
   return if (view == null) {
       View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_spinner, parent).apply {
           tag(Holder(this)) // this is now the new view
       }
   } else { 
       view.apply { (tag as Holder).title.text = getItem(i) }
   }
}
```

or

```
fun getView(i: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
   if (view == null) {
       val tempView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_spinner, parent)
       tempView.tag(Holder(tempView))
       return tempView
   } 

   (view.tag as Holder).title.text = getItem(i)
   return view
}
```

or using the `?.` and `?:` null operators combined with `apply()`:

```
fun getView(i: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    return view?.apply { 
                (tag as Holder).title.text = getItem(i) 
           } ?: View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_spinner, parent).apply {
                     tag(Holder(this))
                }
}
```

And there are another 10 variations, but you can experiment to see what you like.

It is considered less-than-a-good practice (but allowed) to shadow variables by using the same name, that is why it is a compiler warning.  And why you see a change in the variable name above from `view` to `tempView`

Answer (score 11):

Mutable parameters are **not** supported in Kotlin.

I would like to refer you to this [discussion in kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/method-parameters-and-mutable-variables/333/6)

Answer (score 6):

There's a dirty but useful way to achieve that.

```
fun a(b: Int) {
   var b = b
   b++ // this compiles
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I don't know what this does, but I think it does nothing but shut up the compiler and modify the local variable which it then throws away.

Comment: If you re-assign a function parameter in Java, is it not thrown away?
If you don't know what this does, this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @Mitch This does work. What do you mean by "throws away", anyway? The local variable (`var b`) will shadow the passed parameter `b`. Meaning anything that accesses b after this declarations will be accessing the one defined as `var b`

Comment: add `@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")` in android studio or it's gonna annoy you

Comment: this will compile but not function as expected. if you call a(myInt) myint won't change since we have a assignment by value not by reference here. the b++ increments the b inside the function but not outside

Comment: @Johanno I believe the original question is not asking about passing by reference.

Comment: You are changing the value of var b here, not the value of the external variable passed as parameter. It's called the same but it's a different object.

Comment: So annoying that you need to either have a warning, or an even more annoying annotation to suppress said warning. why cant we just change the parameter to var?

Answer (score 1):

Officially speaking, you are not allowed to override a method param. The best you can do is "shadow" the param variable.

So you can do it similar to (not sure why you would want to shadow though but you can)

```
getView(i: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup) {
  val view = view ?: View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_spinner, parent)
                         .apply { tag(Holder(view)) }
  (view.tag as Holder).title.text = getItem(i)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree, mutable method params are not directly supported in Kotlin, but in arrays and lists I found that playground now supports setting members. It is like a wrapper, things inside an object can change, but not setting that object. You also can use values changed like return values now as I tested on JVM Kotlin Playground. Once changed including in a function properties now stay changed.