# How to change a function argument value

Tags: kotlin

How can I change the value of `a` without extra variables?

```
fun doSomething(a: Int) {
    a = 23
}
```

Comment: You can't. That's not allowed.

Comment: Mutable parameters are not supported in Kotlin. Does this answer your question? [How do I make method param mutable in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109098/how-do-i-make-method-param-mutable-in-kotlin)